# Firebase storage getImageURL after uploading to after save URL in firestore(React)?

Tags: reactjs, image, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

I just want to upload an image then get is URL to save to firestore because i want to save the url of that image to an object. I just want the await to wait for the upload to be finished and then to get the url.

Problem is when i try to get the url it says it doesnt exist but when i go to firebase is there.

```
const fileData = await fileUpload(imageHome, values.newHomeTeamName);
const url = await storage.ref(fileData).getDownloadURL();
console.log(url);


const fileUpload = async (image: File, newHomeTeamName: string) => {
    const fileName = formatFileName(image.name, newHomeTeamName);
    const uploadTask = storage.ref(fileName).put(image);
    await uploadTask.on(
      'state_changed',
      snapsphot => {},
      error => {
        console.log(error);
      }
    );
    return fileName;
  };
```

Comment: What's the problem with the code you shared?

Comment: when i get url it says the image doesnt exist but when i go in firebase it is there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `fileUpload` function looks a bit unusual to me. You're using `await` on the [`on()` call](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.UploadTask#on), but that doesn't return a promise. What you should do instead is `wait` on the task itself. So something like:

```
  const fileUpload = async (image: File, newHomeTeamName: string) => {
    const fileName = formatFileName(image.name, newHomeTeamName);
    const uploadTask = storage.ref(fileName).put(image);
    await uploadTask;
    return fileName;
  }
```

Or a bit simpler:

```
  const fileUpload = async (image: File, newHomeTeamName: string) => {
    const fileName = formatFileName(image.name, newHomeTeamName);
    await storage.ref(fileName).put(image);
    return fileName;
  }
```

If you want to handle the error, you can `catch` it in there too. But since all you do is log it, I'd recommend letting it escape and leave it to the runtime to log it.

Answer (score 0):

This is what i did for my app and the url does get stored in the firestore

```
//imports
import { storage, db } from './firebase'
import firebase from 'firebase'

//states or hooks
 const [caption, setCaption] = useState('')
 const [image, setImage] = useState(null)
 const [progress, setProgress] = useState(0)

const handleUpload=()=>{
        const uploadTask = storage.ref(`images/${image.name}`).put(image);

        uploadTask.on(
            'state_changed',
            (snapshot)=>{
                const progress = Math.round(
                    (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) *100
                );
                setProgress(progress)
            },
            (error)=>{
                console.log(error);
                alert(error.message);
            },
            ()=>{
                storage
                    .ref('images')
                    .child(image.name)
                    .getDownloadURL()
                    .then(url =>{
                        db.collection('posts').add({
                            timestamp: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
                            caption: caption,
                            imageUrl: url,
                            username: uploadname
                        });
                        setImage(null);
                        setProgress(0);
                        setCaption("");
                    })
            }
        )
    }
```

The `handleUpload` trigress off when the upload button is clicked

Comment: the problem is that im uploadding two pictures at once so i need 2 urls.

Comment: why doesnt the await wait for upload to be finish, thats what i want

Comment: yeah i see my solution contains index `[0]` when selecting a file to prevent the issue you are facing but **I don't know how to upload two images at once sorry**